# Decoding CssSelector Statements

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, firefox-developer-tools

I'm getting this error:

```
unable to locate element: {"methode":"css selector","selector":".ftMtypSt-Primary> span"}
```

Code is being generated by the FireFox Developer Selenium IDE and exported to Python.

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ftMs-input").send_keys("Dan")
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ftMtypSt-Primary > span").click()
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li:nth-child(4) > div").click()
```

I want to be able to decode these parts of the statements: `.ftMs-input`, `.ftMtypSt-Primary > span` and `li:nth-child(4) > div`

Comment: You can get started here. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp // Once you get a rough understanding from that reference you'll be able to self-answer your question too. :)

Answer (score 0):

The [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors) can be decoded as follows:

- *`.ftMs-input`*: Within a cssSelector *`.`* indicates *classname*. So `.ftMs-input` would search for an element with *classname* as *`ftMs-input`*. As an example:

  ```
  <input class="ftMs-input" ...>
  ```
- *`.ftMtypSt-Primary > span`*: Similarly `.ftMtypSt-Primary` would search for an element with *classname* as *`ftMtypSt-Primary`*, *`>`* indicates immediate descendant, which is a `<span>` tag. As an example:

  ```
  <button class="ftMtypSt-Primary" ...>
    <span>...</span>
  ```
- *`li:nth-child(4) > div`*: Similarly `li:nth-child(4)` would select every `<li>` element that is the forth child of its parent, *`>`* indicates immediate descendant, which is a `<div>` tag. As an example:

  ```
  <ul class="list items" ...>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>
        <div>This node would be selected</div>
    </li>
  ```

---

### tl; dr

[CSS Selector Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)